# React JS: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code

**UserEdit.jsx**

```
import useForm from "../../utils/useForm";
import LoadingBtn from "../../utils/loadingButton";
import { getUser } from "../../store/users/userActions";
const UserEdit = () => {
    //declare form data and scmena
    const formInput = {
        name: "",
    };
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().required().min(3).max(191).label("Name"),
    };

    //dispatch on first mount
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const params = useParams();
    useEffect(() => {
        setErrors({});
        dispatch(getUser(params.id));
    }, []);

    const {
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        formData,
        setFormData,
        errors,
        setErrors,
    } = useForm(formInput, doSubmit, schema);

    function doSubmit() {
        console.log("handle Submit", formData);
    }

    const isSubmitting = useSelector((state) => state.users.isSubmitting);
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.users.user);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect user >>", user);
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            name: user.name,
        });
    }, [user]);

    return (

            <input
                className={`form-control ${
                    errors["name"]
                        ? "is-invalid"
                        : ""
                }`}
                type="text"
                id="name"
                name="name"
                required=""
                placeholder="Enter your name"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={formData.name}
            />

    );
};

export default UserEdit;
```

**UseForm.jsx**

```
const useForm = (formInput, callback, schema = {}) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(formInput);
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
    const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [name]: value,
        });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        //handle error
        setErrors(validate(formData));
        setIsSubmitting(true);
    };

    const validate = (formData) => {
        const { error } = Joi.validate(formData, schema, {
            abortEarly: false,
        });
        if (!error) return {};

        const validataionErrors = {};
        for (let item of error.details) {
            validataionErrors[item.path[0]] = item.message;
        }
        return validataionErrors;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        //check if there are any errors
        if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) {
            callback();
            setIsSubmitting(true);
        }
    }, [errors]);

    return {
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        formData,
        setFormData,
        errors,
        setErrors,
    };
};

export default useForm;
```

I googled about the error and it mentioned that state need to be initialized at first with the field. However, I have already defined initial state as

```
    const formInput = {
        name: "",
    };
```

I could not find how could I fix this, I am open to restructure the `useForm` hooks if that is the one which causing trouble.

currently, if I uncomment the following line on userEdit.jsx, the warning will be gone, but also the edit form becomes empty as well

```
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            name: user.name,
        });
```

Comment: That's quite a lot of code, you should really cut it down to only the relevant parts. Regardless, an uncontrolled state means the `value` prop is getting undefined. If you debug your code and check when `formData.name` is undefined you should be able to fix it

Comment: @Jason could you take a look on it. I think formData.name might be undefined at the first render, but I can't define formData, formData is currently being returned from useForm.

Comment: Make this bit in the input `value={formData.name}` to `value={formData.name || ""}` It will take care of the error message.

Comment: `value={formData.name ?? ''}`

Comment: @reoberto looks like this does the trick but I am not sure that I am using the useForm hook in the correct way, am I handeling it in incorrect way? or there is nothing to be concerned.

Comment: You should probably just return formData as `null`or `''` instead of `undefined`

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković how could I do that dynamically in `useForm` should I map all field and return or what would be the clean way to do so

Comment: Actually, I have passed `formInput` as the default value to the useForm, how could I set / returned that as formData until handleChange?